# How to include a variable in 'r' raw string

Tags: python, rawstring

I've created a new variable for user path, but not sure how to add in to the following.

```
import os, pwd

path=os.getcwd()

#crif0 = r '/abc/crif/gpio_mem_0_crif.xml' - original

crif0 = r (path+ '/crif/gpio_mem_0_crif.xml') - I tried with this but doesn't work
```

Comment: You have to use `path + r'/crif/...'`

Comment: In this particular case, `os.path.join(path, 'crif', 'gpio_mem_0_crif.xml')` is the proper way.

Comment: `r` is not a *function* but only a *notation*. Just like the `0x` in `0xA5` - you can't separate that either.

Comment: @bereal thanks! pls answer below so i can close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, `r` is a literal prefix which you cannot apply to anything but string literals, so `path + r'/crif/...'` is enough. However, in this particular case when you need to compose a file path, I'd use the standard library, which makes the code more portable:

```
import os
path = os.getcwd()
crif0 = os.path.join(path, 'crif', 'gpio_mem_0_crif.xml')
```

or, in a more modern way using path objects rather than strings:

```
from pathlib import Path
crif0 = Path.cwd() / 'crif' / 'gpio_mem0_crif.xml'
```